# Trouble in starting Jenkins slave(agent) on the USS of z/OS

Tags: jenkins, mainframe, zos

The Jenkins Master is running on a separate Linux(ubuntu) machine and launching the slave via SSH on USS using java at `/usr/lpp/java/J8.0_64`. The error log for slave start is as below:

```
[02/14/19 11:44:14] [SSH] Starting slave process: export _CEE_RUNOPTS='FILETAG(AUTOCVT,AUTOTAG) POSIX(ON)' && export IBM_JAVA_ENABLE_ASCII_FILETAG=ON && export _BPX_AUTOCVT=ON && cd "/ODVPLEX/share/mnt/jenkins" && /usr/lpp/java/J8.0_64/bin/java -Xmx1024m -Djava.io.tmpdir=/ODVPLEX/share/mnt/jenkins/tmp -Dfile.encoding=iso8859-1 -Xnoargsconversion -jar slave.jar -text
Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile slave.jar
Slave JVM has terminated. Exit code=1
[02/14/19 11:44:15] Launch failed - cleaning up connection
```

I made the configuration as mentioned in [this link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6T76_1.0.2/jenkinsintegration.html) but this hasn't worked.

If anyone succeeded in starting the jenkins slave on USS (z/OS) then please let me know and also what I am missing to make it working.

Comment: Have you confirmed that `slave.jar` isn't... invalid or corrupt? Are you able to run other Java applications with that JVM?

Comment: slave.jar which gets copied by Jenkins launch agent process is not the corrupt one..If I simply copy that jar to usual Linux machine then I can do jar -tvf as well but not on this z/OS machine....I know that there is a problem with the file system but what am I missing to make it work ....

Comment: How did you copy the slave.jar to USS?   if you used `scp` it may have corrupted the file as scp on z/OS seems to do some conversion of chars.  I've had good success with `ftp`in bin mode.  You should be able to do a `jar tvf slave.jar` and get the output of the contents.  If you don't the file was corrupted in transit.